# 419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.This error appears when i submit the form

Tags: laravel

I got this error even when I give `{{ csrf_field() }}` during form submission.

What could be the issue?

```html
<form action="{{ route('e-account-post') }}" method="POST" id="e-account" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="field-label">Full Name <span class="required">*</span></div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" value="" placeholder="Full Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <button class="btn credit-btn mt-30" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

below is route

```php
Route::post('/e-account','FrontController@e_account_action')->name('e-account-post');
```

below is controller

```php
public function e_account_action(Request $request)
{
   dd($request->all());
}
```

Laravel 5.7 and the project is live.

There is no problem in local. I setup the project in live mode through GitLab.

Comment: Did you tried with route alias without - signs. For example with name('e_account_post')    Also make sure that you have cleared your view caches... php artisan view:clear

Comment: view page source and verify that a token is generated

Comment: Do you have your session driver set to file on the prod server?

Comment: check whether your app key is set or not in the env file

Comment: @boolfalse ya i have cleared the view and cache as well

Comment: @Saly3301 token is generated.

Comment: @Alec Joy session driver is set to file

Comment: @ab_ app key is also set